# Failed linking file resources when using Motion Layout KeyPosition

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx, android-motionlayout

I am getting

> "Failed linking file resources"

with

> "error: attribute type (aka com.testapp.client:type) not found"

When using the new MotionLayout, specifically when adding a KeyPosition element to the scene file.

My scene file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/recyclerview"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="60"
            app:target="@id/toolbar_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="255" />
        </KeyAttribute>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="90"
            app:target="@id/toolbar_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="0" />
        </KeyAttribute>
        <KeyPosition
            app:type="pathRelative"
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:target="@id/title"
            app:percentX="0.9" />
    </KeyFrameSet>
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:scaleX="1.0"
        android:scaleY="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.625"
        android:scaleY="0.625"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar_image" />

</ConstraintSet>
```

I am using Android Studio 3.2 stable, and AndroidX varients of the support libs & constraint layout.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind :)

Attribute "type" on KeyPosition element has been changed in Alpha 2 to be "keyPositionType"

here is a snippet if anyone is having the same issues:

```
        <KeyPosition
            app:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:target="@id/title"
            app:percentX="0.9" />
```

instead of this:

```
        <KeyPosition
            app:type="pathRelative"
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:target="@id/title"
            app:percentX="0.9" />
```

Comment: Just a note, could also be the `target` attribute that should be `motionTarget` now as of alpha 4

Comment: In my case `interpolator` was renamed to `motionInterpolator`. You can check all the changes [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/04/constraintlayout-200-alpha-4.html).

Answer (score 13):

For your information, `target`

has been changed to `motionTarget`

in `KeyPosition` and `KeyAttribute`

Comment: This is the solution in my case. I got the error of target after update library. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

As @MichałK mentioned in comments in seems to be that

`android:interpolator` have changed to `motion:motionInterpolator`

in a later version

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout.html#transition

---

**Old Post:**

In addition to what @Momen mentioned

In `<Transition ...>` tag `motion:interpolator`

have been changed to `android:interpolator`

( Change of namespace from `motion` to `android` )

**example:**

```
<Transition ...
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
```

Comment: It has probably changed again, because for 2.0.0-beta2 it's `motion:motionInterpolator`